# Filtering file names with Get-Content

Tags: powershell

EDIT:

This seems to work. Hope it helps someone:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\RD | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^[^8]*141.txt"} | 
Foreach-Object {$_ 
                Get-Content -Path C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\RD\$_ | 
                Out-File C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\RD\141Master.txt
               }
```

---

I'm trying to work out filtering file names for a more explicit appending process. So I can do this:

```
Get-Content C:\erik\*.txt | Out-File C:\erik\whatever.txt
```

And all the text files append. Then I can do this:

```
Get-Content C:\erik\*101.txt | Out-File C:\erik\whatever.txt
```

And all the files with 101 in them append. But when I try something like this:

```
Get-Content C:\erik\^[^8]*141.txt | Out-File C:\erik\whatever.txt
```

I get:

> Get-Content : An object at the specified path
>   C:\Users\edarling\Desktop\RD\^[^8]*141.txt does not exist, or has been
>   filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-Content C:\Users\edarling\Desktop\RD\^[^8]*141.txt | Out-File C:\Users\edarl ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

I've been trying to pipe Get-ChildItem to Get-Content, but can't quite figure it out. Any suggestions out there?

Thanks

Comment: `^[^8]*` this is REGEX ?

Comment: If you find a solution to your problem yourself it's perfectly acceptable to post and accept an answer to your own question. Please don't update your question with the answer, though, because questions can't be accepted, meaning there's no indication that the problem is actually resolved.

Comment: I tried to reply and answer, but I don't have the rep points to do that. I got a message saying to edit my question. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You need a minimum reputation of 50 to be able to comment on someone else's question or answer, but you can post questions as well as answers right from the start. Use the black button "Post Your Answer" at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` supports only [globbing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). With the former you can only do things like this:

- match all file names that end with `141.txt`: `*141.txt`
- match all file names that begin with `foo` and end with a `d` or `t`: `foo*[dt]`
- match all file names that consist of two arbitrary characters followed by the extension `.doc`: `??.doc`

Globbing does not allow you to form an expression to match a name that does *not* contain particular characters. To `Get-Content` your expression `^[^8]*141.txt` means "a file name that begins with a caret followed by either another caret or the character 8 and ends with 141.txt".

If you need to filter by regular expression you have to use the `-match` operator:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' | ? { $_.Name -match '^[^8]*141\.txt$' }
```

Note that in regular expressions you need to escape dots if you want to match literal dots (`\.`). Unescaped dots matche any character except a line feed. You should also anchor your expression on both sides. Otherwise a regular expression `^[^8]*141.txt` would match not only `abc141.txt`, but also something like `141_txt.doc`.